# C - 2 conditions in if statements

Tags: c, conditional-statements

hope you have a solution for me, here my matter:

```
if (!strcmp(bgcolor,"RED")&& (ekey & keyup) {*strncpy(bgcolor,"GREY",5);}
```

How can i execute this in the right way?

Edit: Thanks, newbie here,

Edit: ehm... what about this?

```
if  (ekey & keyB && (ekey & keyup && (!strcmp(bgcolor,"RED")))) {*strncpy(bgcolor,"GREY",5);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your snippet, more specifcally the parentheses are not matched properly (you are missing the closing paren surrounding the *if-condition*).

You are probably looking for something as:

```
if (!strcmp (bgcolor, "RED") && (ekey & keyup)) {
  strncpy (bgcolor, "GREY", 5);
}
```

<sup>**Note:** Notice the `))` after `keyup`...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!strcmp(bgcolor,"RED") && (ekey & keyup))
{
    strncpy(bgcolor,"GREY",5);
}
```